# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in php need tip

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 231.

Here's my lines around 231

```
//if($_SESSION['ID'] == '1275')
$APILinks = array();
foreach($APILinkIds as $APIId) $APILinks[] = $APILinkAll[$APIId];
    $APILinks[] = $mainAPILink;
//}
```

Comment: Assuming that `foreach` line is line 231, `$APILinkIds` probably isn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

What the error is telling you is that the argument supplied to the `foreach` construct (*which is `$APILinkIds` in this case*) is not a valid argument. Valid arguments to `foreach` are traversable objects such as `Array` or any object that implements the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/traversable) interface. You can examine the variable by using [`var_dump($APILinkIds)`](http://php.net/var-dump) and the variable's type and value will be printed for you to inspect. If it is an object you can determine if it implements `Traversable` by using the [`instanceof`](http://php.net/instanceof) type operator or [`is_a`](http://php.net/is-a) function. Additionally objects' public properties are traversable by default such that something like...

`$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 1;
$obj->bar = 2;
foreach($obj as $value)
    echo "$value\n";`

will give you ...

`1
2`